# Does pt. file contains models?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, yolo

I am new and working on object detection. I trained my model from colab and downloaded .pt folder. When I tried to torch.load(path), 'models' can not found. I tried to check what is included in .pt file with print(torch.load(PATH)) and gave me load error. Do .pt files contain models in all circumstances, when we are working with YOLO or not?

The error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/mev/dev_ws/install/cv_basics/lib/cv_basics/img_subscriber_YOLO7", line 11, in 
> load_entry_point('cv-basics==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'img_subscriber_YOLO7')()
> File "/home/mev/dev_ws/install/cv_basics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv_basics/webcam_sub_YOLOV7.py", line 88, in main
> image_subscriber = ImageSubscriber()
> File "/home/mev/dev_ws/install/cv_basics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv_basics/webcam_sub_YOLOV7.py", line 54, in **init**
> print(torch.load('./best.pt'))
> File "/home/mev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 789, in load
> return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
> File "/home/mev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1131, in _load
> result = unpickler.load()
> File "/home/mev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1124, in find_class
> return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Comment: Please add the full error traceback with questions.

Comment: I added the error file, as you wish. Actually I could not understand the whole error, as I said before I am new. However, the important thing here is --> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Comment: Not sure exactly what causes this, but here is the same error people reported https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18325

Comment: I saw this but it did not work for me. After trials lots of things, I realized that I can run the same code with python3 <filename>, it works. However if I run with ros2 run <file name>, I received ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' error. Please, if you any idea, share with me, I need your help...